# parent-child relation NOT returning parent name using NavUtils.getParentActivityName(this) in child activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have one activity Called `A`. and I am starting another activity `B` like this

```
 Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),B.class);
    i.putExtra(BFragment.EXTRA_CRIME_ID, c.getmId());
    startActivity(i);
```

The above code I assumed that activity `A` is a parent of `B`.

But when I try to access name of parent which is `A` in activity `B` like this

```
NavUtils.getParentActivityName(this)
```

It giving me empty string. why is this. When we start new activity using intent, dont we mean that the `A` is the parent of `B`

How can I access `A` name? How can I create parent-child relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent relations should be marked on the manifest, like the following code:

```
 <activity android:name=".B"
            android:parentActivityName="com.alex.myapp.MainActivity">
     <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
     <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.alex.myapp.MainActivity"/>
  </activity>
```